# ggplot in r: duplicate faceted geom_density and geom_density_ridges results

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

The default settings for `ggplot2::geom_density()` with a facet and `ggridges::geom_density_ridges()` yield slightly different curves.  How can I modify the smoothing technique in one or the other to yield the same result?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

# standard density with facet by cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_density(fill = "gray") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4)), ncol = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# density ridge with y = cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_minimal()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 1.38
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same stat that `geom_density()` uses.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

# standard density with facet by cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_density(fill = "gray") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4)), ncol = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# density ridge with y = cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "density", aes(height = stat(density))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Alternatively, you can take the bandwidth that `geom_density_ridges()` reports and use it in `geom_density()` (here, `bw = 1.38`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

# density ridge with y = cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_minimal()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 1.38
```

[image]

```r
# standard density with facet by cyl ----
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_density(fill = "gray", bw = 1.38) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4)), ncol = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The final two plots look slightly different because they have different x axis limits.